Block Matrix eigenvalues
I am working on a complicated optimization problem. I define $I\in \mathbb{N}, I > 1,  n_I=\binom{I}{2}$. I try to optimize a scalar-valued function $\mathcal{O} : \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. To do so, I end up looking to the Hessian matrix to prove that my optimum is truly an optimum (I need $\mathbf{H}$ to be positive-definite). As you have noticed, I need to study the application in generality, that is without fixing a value for $I$. To do so, I look for an induction proof observing that:
$$\mathbf{H}_{I+1} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{H}_{I} & R \\ R^T & M\end{pmatrix}$$
with $\mathbf{H}_{I+1} \in \mathcal{M}_{n_{I+1}\times n_{I+1}}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbf{H}_{I} \in \mathcal{M}_{n_{I}\times n_{I}}(\mathbb{R}), M \in \mathcal{M}_{(n_{I+1}-n_{I})\times (n_{I+1}-n_{I})}(\mathbb{R}), R \in \mathcal{M}_{n_{I}\times (n_{I+1}-n_{I})}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbf{H}$ and M being both symetric matrices.
To help you to get a better grasp of the problem, I write you $\mathbf{H}_4$ with ($S_k$ and $G_k$ positive scalars):
$$\mathbf{H}_{4} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
G_1 + G_2 + S_1 + S_2 &S_1 &S_2 &S_1 &S_2 &0 \\
S_1 &G_1+G_3+S_1+S_3 &S_3 & S_1 &0 &S_3\\
S_2 & S_3 &G_2+G_3+S_2+S_3 &0 &S_2 &S_3 \\
\hline\\
S_1 & S_1 & 0 & G_1+G_4+S_1+S_4 & S_4 & S_4 \\
S_2 & 0 & S_2 & S_4 &G_2+G_4+S_2+S_4 &S_4\\
0 &S_3 &S_3 &S_4 &S_4 &G_3+G_4+S_3+S_4
\end{array}\right) $$
I think that the characteristic polynomial is not easily factorizable in $\mathbb{R}$. My hope was to try an induction proof with hypothesis $h_I$ : "All eigenvalues of $\mathbf{H}_{I}$ are non-negative". I come here to ask you: what would you do in my situation? is my methodology correct? Is there a formula to help me compute eigenvalues for matrices like this one?
Any help will be much appreciated.

So you want $H_{I+1}$ to be pd based on the knowledge that $H_I$ is? Do you know that the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive?

@AnCar "So you want $\mathbf{H}_{i+1}$ to be pd based on the knowledge that $\mathbf{H}_I$  is?" That was my idea considering I have not spotted an obvious pattern in the characteristic polynomial. For $M$, I think -but have not yet proved-, that its eigenvalues are non-negative too.

Let $x$ be a column vector that can be multiplied on the left by $H$ and $y$ one that can multiplied on the left by $M$. Then what you want is that $(x^T,y^T)\begin{pmatrix} H & R \ R^T & M\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\y \end{pmatrix}>0$ for all such choices $x,y$. This simplifies to $x^T Hx+y^T M y > -2 \langle x, Ry\rangle$. If $M$ is positive definite you know the LHS will be strictly positive, but you will still need to get the inequality by some control over $R$. For example, something like having that $\langle x, Ry\rangle=0$.

Thank you @AnCar. Nonetheless, R is not positive definite and I can't add some controls to make it positive definite...

No, no, $R$ need not be positive definite. All you need is that $x^T Hx+y^T My+2\langle x,Ry\rangle>0$.

no, for example consider the simple case where $\begin{bmatrix} H & R \ R^T & M\end{bmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \ 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$. $2x^2 + 3y^2 + 2xy>0$ for all $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, even if $xy<0$, where $xy=\langle x, Ry\rangle$ in this case.
